# How to fill combo box in a td of a table

Tags: php, sql, html, pdo, combobox

I want to retrieve some data from the database and show them in a table, i need to make one field `Order_Status` to be as a combo box, its data is filled from another table and to add in the beginning of the combo the result of the row returned from the database.

[Data Sample from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8HJn.png)

The data needed to be like the below, in the red section to be combobox.
[Required Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVo5g.png)

**The problem** is that i couldn't put the result for the field `Order_status` to appear as a combo box in the td of the table

```
$stmt ="SELECT distinct Order_ID,Customer_ID,Required_Date,Order_Status FROM Orders where Required_Date between '".$SDate."' and '".$EDate."'";
$row = $conn->query($stmt)->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($row) > 0)
{
    $output.='<hr />
            <table class="table1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Order No.</th>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>Order Details</th>
                    <th>Delivery Date</th>
                    <th>Order Status</th>
                </tr>
    ';
    foreach ($conn->query($stmt) as $rows) 
    {
        //Getting Customer Name
        $sql="SELECT nick_name_ FROM Customers where Cust_id='".$rows["Customer_ID"]."'";
        $result=$conn->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //Getting Order Data
        $query="SELECT * FROM Order_Product where Order_ID='".$rows["Order_ID"]."'";

        foreach ($conn->query($query) as $results) 
        {
            $newsql="SELECT Category_Name from Categories where Category_ID='".$results['Category_ID']."'";
            $newresult=$conn->query($newsql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $CatName=$newresult['Category_Name'];

            $newsql="SELECT Product_Name from Products where Product_ID='".$results['Product_ID']."'";
            $newresult=$conn->query($newsql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $ProName=$newresult['Product_Name'];

            $output.='
            <tr>
                <td>'.$rows['Order_ID'].'</td>
                <td>'.$result['nick_name_'].'</td>
                <td>'.$CatName.",".$ProName." ".$results['Amount'].'</td>
                <td>'.$rows['Required_Date'].'</td>
            ';
            $stmt = "SELECT * FROM Order_Status WHERE Status_Name !='".$rows['Order_Status']."'";
            //$res = $conn->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            foreach ($conn->query($stmt) as $res) 
            {

                $output.='<td>'
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $res['Status_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $res['Status_Name']; ?></option>
                <?php
                '</td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }

        }
    }

    $output.='</table>';
    $bool_is_data_saved = true;
    echo $output;
}

if(!$bool_is_data_saved)
{
    echo ("Failed");
}
```

Comment: This is jacked up! What is the problem you are having? Why do you foreach a query statement as  a row>???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is... hard to read...

To me it seems cleaner to do the following instead of the foreach on the actual query:

```
$stmnt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?");
$stmnt->execute(array($someId));
while ($result = $stmnt->fetch()){
    //do stuff
}
```

Also, breaking out of the PHP in the foreach to then turn around and echo inside the HTML is odd. Clean that up.

Lastly, in order to make this more manageable, I would use a couple of functions that you call from the HTML. Put the functions in the top of the doc.

To answer your question, I think the problem is that you do not define a select.

do this:

```
$output.='<td>';
$output .= '<select name="comboBox">';

foreach ($conn->query($stmt) as $res) {
    $output .= '<option value="'.$res['Status_ID'] .'">'.$res['Status_Name'],'</option>';
}
$output .= '</select>';
$output .= '</td>';
```

**One more thing!**
You are using $stmnt variable in two different places for two different queries. either use a different variable or put your queries in functions.